# Website .htaccess language redirection only at the beginning of the session

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using this code on my website's .htaccess for redirection based on browser language:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=es [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.com/ambienteTrabajo/?lang=es [L,R=301]
```

It works and redirects according to browser language, but it forces that all the time never letting you change to another one: if you try to manually select another language the site tries to load but gets immediately thrown back to the one that matches your browser configuration.

I want visitors to be able to choose language at any time, so, is there any way I can make that code work redirecting only at the beginning of the session?

Answer (score 0):

**Update :** clear your browser cache and test the following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^   https://www.example.com/ambienteTrabajo/?lang=es [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^   https://www.example.com/ambienteTrabajo/?lang=en [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Yes I did. But it didn't work. It keeps forcing redirection ALWAYS.

Comment: I think you should make rule to every language as well

Comment: the website has two languages: english and spanish, but I can't figure out how to make those rules for both of them... right now it checks the url and if it doesn't contain "lang=es" then redirects to spanish; if I create that same rule for english, then it would never redirect to spanish in the first place. Sorry for my lack of expertise.